# How to delete rows from one table matching another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete rows from one table. So this what i have done so far. I imported a .CSV file which created a temp table. I would like to delete the rows in my original table with matching with temp table.

I tried the following code :

```
Delete From Table1 
Where postid and userid in (Select postid, userid 
                            from Table2)
```

but it does not work.

The goal is to delete rows in Table 1 using Table 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` should do the job:

```
DELETE T1
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.postid = T2.postid
AND T1.userid = T2.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just another funny way :

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE STR(postid) + STR(userid) 
IN (SELECT STR(postid) + STR(userid) FROM Table2)
```

Comment: This won't work in sql server if the `postid` or `userid` is a GUID. Nice approach though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to Delete from Table1 where you want to create a composite  condition based on postid and userid the from Table2 the   problem is that you subquery in(Select postid,userid from 
Table2) is not returning the correct value as to match the in condition please modify the query to

```
DELETE T1
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.postid = T2.postid
AND T1.userid = T2.userid
```

as stated in the previous answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Merge statement.  In this case you're only interested in deletes. A semicolon is required after the delete section, followed by a final semicolon to end the merge statement. For example:

```
MERGE table1 AS target USING table2 AS source
ON target.postid = source.postid and target.userid = source.userid
WHEN Matched THEN DELETE;;
```

An example sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a932d/1/0

The Merge documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql